# How to launch the hidden Sound Recorder on Froyo?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, home-screen-shortcuts

I discovered a "Sound Recorder" in the application list on my Froyo handset. Why is it hidden like that with no 'launcher' or app icon to start it?

I'm curious.. also because of this [app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pete.recorder&hl=en);
I need to open this thing and I want to know how to do it since it is already on my phone. I don't want to pay for an app that is just a shortcut.

NOTE: I recently flashed an unofficial cyanogenmod ROM for my phone and it has the hidden sound recorder shortcut now on the application drawer.

Comment: You're asking for a lot of speculation here. Your second paragraph is basically unanswerable unless the developer himself answers it.

Comment: Well, we do prefer concrete, **answerable** questions. (Read the [FAQ].) The only concrete question I can see is "How can I access the 'Sound Recorder' functionality of Android without going through a third-party (paid) app?" Or possibly "What is the 'Sound Recorder' I see in my application list?"

Comment: @Al Everett Alright, I just need to open the sound recorder app without using his app. Any idea? Terminal?

Comment: Well next time, I'll think about posting it as different questions; I just seem to link everything up in a single post, sorry. and hoping that next time I won't encounter any "similar post" comments when I do that. (ps. I made the question clear now, hopefully)

Comment: Yes, better, thanks. Please note that I wasn't being critical, only pointing out that you weren't likely to get helpful answers. Now I just hope someone knows something about Sound Recorder, because I'm curious about it now, too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1358/discussion-between-power-inside-and-al-everett)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try launching it from the command line using the `am` command. Either from a terminal emulator or from an `adb` shell you can try:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.soundrecorder/com.android.soundrecorder.SoundRecorder
```

This works on my EVO and on my Xoom, and it's probably important to note that my Xoom does **not** display the Sound Recorder application in my app drawer (similar to your device).

Also, some custom launchers let you define shortcuts to either an activity or an intent. In ADW Launcher, for example, you can choose to set a shortcut to the Sound Recorder activity by long pressing your home screen and going to `Custom Shortcut->Pick your activity` and then finding it in the list (it lists every activity on the device).

Answer (score 0):

CyanogenMod 6 (which is Froyo) has this available, so my guess is that your phone manufacturer or carrier has hidden it. Post more details about those two things.

Comment: That's very unlikely because I did /cust WIPE and /ALL wipe and am running a custom ROM. The hidden app still exists on the new ROM too. Right now im running Dronix 0.4 ROM (based on 2.2 froyo itself) and its Huawei IDEOS u8150.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you asked for, but it might solve your problem. If you *just* want to be able to make short audio recordings from your phone, you can use the “Note to self” functionality of Voice Search.

Trigger Voice Search, say “Note to self” (on my phone it also appears by default in the text search results list before you type anything, but I think that might be new in Gingerbread) and then anything. A dialog will appear with a transcription of the recording, and options for sending an e-mail. If you just send it, you will recieve in your Gmail a message containing the transcription *and the original audio*.

Comment: Sounds nice.. but its slow and needs internet connection; also voice commands are currently for US English/Generic language inputs only. thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that might help you. I have huawei ideos u8150 and I use messages whenever I want to record any audio.
Go to 'message' then 'create new message'. Select the menu button then select 'attach' Select record audio and the sound recorder is launched. After recording you can discard the message since the recorded audio has been stored on your SD card